# add row to table from onload jquery

Tags: jquery, addition, dynamic, rows

I have the following table

```
<table id="invoice">
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th><input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add Row"  />
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="id1">
      <td><input id="quantity1" name="quantity[]" tabindex="1" type="text" value=""  /></td>
      <td><select id="rate1" name="rate[]" tabindex="2" value="">
          <option value="">SELECT</option>
          <option value="1">ONE</option>
          <option value="2">TWO</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><input  id="remove1"  name="remove[]"  tabindex="3"  type="button" value="Remove Row"class="remove"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I am able to add row using the following script

```
var next = 2;
function addrow(table,add)
{
  $(add).bind('click', function() {   
    var $last = $(table + ' tr:last');
    var last_row = $last.clone();  
    $(last_row).find(":input").each(function() {
      var store = $(this).attr("id");
      var new1 = store.replace(/1/, next);
      $(this).attr("id",new1);
    });
    last_row.appendTo($(table))
    $(table+" tr:last").hide().fadeIn('slow');
     next++;  
  });
}
addrow('#invoice','#addnew');
```

[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ullasvk2000/Up5PY/1/)

the above script clones the 2nd row and append to the table which is actually required. But the problem is if user inputs some value in the 2nd row of the text box and after that clicks addrow, it replicates this in the new row with the values.To overcome this i just chnges the script.

SO i changed the script to the following

```
var next = 2;
function addrow(table,add)
{
  var $last = $(table + ' tr:last');///changed this line
  var last_row = $last.clone(); /// changed this line  
  $(add).bind('click', function() {   

    $(last_row).find(":input").each(function() {
      var store = $(this).attr("id");
      var new1 = store.replace(/1/, next);
      $(this).attr("id",new1);
    });
    last_row.appendTo($(table))
    $(table+" tr:last").hide().fadeIn('slow');
    next++;  
  });
}
```

[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ullasvk2000/BCK95/1/)

This adds only one row,it just changes the last row,but not add more than new row.

Can any one please correct this second script as this works perfect for my project as many other scripts are associated with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var next = 2;

function addrow(table, add) {
    var $last = $(table + ' tr:last'); ///changed this line
    var last_row = $last.clone(); /// changed this line  
    $(add).bind('click', function() {
        var localClone = last_row.clone(); // you want to clone the DOM row.
        $(localClone).find(":input").each(function() {
            var store = $(this).attr("id");
            var new1 = store.replace(/1/, next);
            $(this).attr("id", new1);
        });
        localClone.appendTo($(table));
        $(table + " tr:last").hide().fadeIn('slow');
        next++;
    });
}
```

You want to create a new clone / DOM row each time you click it. Otherwise you just keep moving one row around.

So we have our original last row to clone at the start and we keep cloning the "clean row". The clean row stays clean because `last_row` is never added to the DOM.

@patrickdw mentioned another option which is to keep cloning the last row inside the click function but clearing the data of the row. Depending on what your row is like cleaning it up each time might be worthwhile.

The nice thing about @patrickdw method is that you can clean up some data but keep other data. This might be useful for you.

Comment: +1 I think the local clone is the way to go. Always starts with a duplicate of the row in its initial state. Values can be replicated if needed. ...I'd just point out that the ID of the row is being duplicated, but that's a side issue from the original code.